# Anagramming in sixes

Tags: anagram

Fill in the gaps in the following conversations. All six gaps contain the same six letters in a different order, with spaces and punctuation where appropriate.

**Conversation #1**

> – Have you ever ______ James? One of my favourites, I must say.
>   – I don't think I have. Hey, does anyone want a beer?
>   – Yeah! Grab me a ______, will you?

**Conversation #2**

> – Any word from the new group ______ yet?
>   – Not that I know of. I'm excited to see what he's like, though.
>   – Absolutely. I think the success of groups depends a lot on how they ______.

**Conversation #3**

> – Alright gentlemen, place your bets. Jimmy's first to act.
>   – Wait a minute. What's this, ______? You gave me too many cards.
>   – Sorry, I got distracted. I'm going to have to ______.

Comment: This question is featured in the Puzzling Stack Exchange Newsletter of Monday, July 29, 2019. Congratulations, and well done! :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Conversation #1

– Have you ever ______ James? One of my favourites, I must say.

> read E. L.

– I don't think I have. Hey, does anyone want a beer?

– Yeah! Grab me a ______, will you?

> Red Ale

Conversation #2

– Any word from the new group ______ yet?

> Leader

– Not that I know of. I'm excited to see what he's like, though.

– Absolutely. I think the success of groups depends a lot on how they ______.

> Are led

Conversation #3

– Alright gentlemen, place your bets. Jimmy's first to act.

– Wait a minute. What's this, ______? You gave me too many cards.

> Dealer

– Sorry, I got distracted. I'm going to have to ____

> Redeal