# Twelve past eleven at the police station

Tags: wordplay, story, anagram

An immeasurably large kudos to [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86559/anagramming-in-sixes), which was the inspiration for this one.

All of the blanks in the following passage may be filled with words. Each of the seven blanks contains one distinct word, which is the anagram of every other word in every other blank.

> *Interrogation room, 11:12 am*
>
> Jimmy's shaking in his _____. He knows that he's innocent, but he suddenly has a dark thought. What if the people to question him are convinced that he had shoplifted that electronics store? Then it would be simply impossible for him to _____ their appetite for questioning and dampen their hopes of finding a loophole. Even worse, would they torture him for answers? Give him one heck of a _____, perhaps? The anticipation of that painful weapon being used quickens his heart's pace even further.
>
> He shakes his head again. *No*, he thinks to himself, *just deny everything*. He hadn't been the one to break into the store. He had just been carrying a wrench over to his friend's home to fix her plumbing, and had only turned the corner next to the newly-robbed convenience store when he was roughly stopped and locked in the back of a cop car.
>
> A tall man comes into the room, and Jimmy's heart skips three beats in a row. *This is the interrogator. I'm dead meat*, he thinks, finding no comfort in the stranger's imposing figure. Even the symbols on his shirt look frighteningly mysterious. They looked like Greek to Jimmy, literally. He thought he saw rhos, sigmas, maybe even _____. Suddenly, the man takes out a bag of chips stuffed in his right pants pocket and violently rips it open, sending some spuds flying. Then, with a look of disgust on his face, he _____ its contents, grumbling that they weren't the kind of chips he wanted. Then he turns to Jimmy.
>
> "My name's Brian Roberts," said the man, sweeping up some chips from the floor and tossing them in the trash bin. "I'm not your interrogator today, but I wanted to know... what was the address of the store that was broken into earlier?"
>
> Relaxing slightly, Jimmy replies. "I think it was 2480 _____ Street, sir."
>
> "That's good," says the man, and returns to cleaning up his mess with a few colorful words. "Anyway, they sent me to tell you that they took fingerprints from the place and it wasn't you. You're free to leave."
>
> With a sigh of relief, Jimmy picks himself up and heads for the door. It's time to go home. Maybe watch some football. Maybe get a bowl of ice cream. Maybe indulge in a delicious mix of _____.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jimmy's shaking in his _____.

> seat

Then it would be simply impossible for him to _____ their appetite for questioning and dampen their hopes of finding a loophole.

> sate

Give him one heck of a _____, perhaps?

> tase

He thought he saw rhos, sigmas, maybe even _____.

> etas

Then, with a look of disgust on his face, he _____ its contents, grumbling that they weren't the kind of chips he wanted.

> eats

Relaxing slightly, Jimmy replies. "I think it was 2480 _____ Street, sir."

> East

Maybe indulge in a delicious mix of _____.

> teas, although I'm less certain about this one.

Comment: Congratulations! That's exactly correct!

Comment: Strangely enough, I've never heard the phrase "delicious mix of _" before.

Comment: I had doubts upon reaching that last one too, but the other ones fit into place really well.

Comment: I was going to say rot13(qryvpvbhf oyraq bs), but I thought that was going to be too obvious.